# Как получить данные из массива, который внутри объекта?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Я делаю json парсер и мне нужен универсальный метод, который работает с любыми типами данных, так что Я не могу просто сделать так `int[] arr = obj as int[];`

```
 int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
 object obj = array;
//Мне надо получить значения из 'obj'
```

Comment: `if (obj is int[] ints)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я сказал с любыми типами данных

Comment: `if (obj is Array arr)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне на англоязычном StackOverFlow 3 часа не могли помочь... А тут моментально ответ и причём который мне помог. Даже смешно стало. Сделай этот вариант полноценным ответом, чтобы я мог тебя отметить

Comment: А я считаю это плохим решением. Я уже приготовился задавать дополнительные вопросы: откуда берётся этот `obj`, почему данные кастятся к `object` и т. п. Ведь лучше сразу делать правильную диспетчеризацию по конкретным типам.

Comment: Напиши ответ сам. Это не возбраняется и даже поощряется. И потом прими его.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я делаю json парсер и сейчас реализую преобразование массива любых типов данных в  строку формата json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо Alexander Petrov за ответ

```
 if(obj is Array arr) {
    foreach( var item in arr ) {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
 }
```